# MongoDB: use MongoImport with csv to update single field only

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update a single field in each document in my collection using a csv and Mongoimport with –upsert included.
However the process removes all other fields in the document.

I have a Books Collection with documents like:

```
{

    "_id" : "knOIv8ZUUK", 
    "Price" : 2.2, 
    "Title" : "Rats Ahoy"
}

{

    "_id" : "okYEGuWznv", 
    "Price" : 3.3, 
    "Title" : "Friendly Fish"
}
```

a csv file:

```
_id,Price

knOIv8ZUUK,2.2

okYEGuWznv,3.3
```

And import using:

```
mongoimport  --db local  --collection Books --upsert  --type csv  
             --headerline  --file c:\import\newPrice
```

With results deleting the Title field

```
{ 

    "_id" : "knOIv8ZUUK", 
    "Price" : 2.2
}

{ 

    "_id" : "okYEGuWznv", 
    "Price" : 3.3
}
```

I, incorrectly, thought Upsert would just update an imported field.
So is there another process I can use to update just 1 field in large number of documents?
thanks

Comment: Hi @MarkM, were you able resolve? Please share the solution if you were. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

From [mongoimport --upsertFields doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-upsertfields)
You can need to use mode merge:

> Merge existing documents that match a document in the import file with the new document. mongoimport will insert all other documents. Merge Matching Documents during Import describes how to use --mode merge.

and specify the field name, default is '_id'

```
--mode merge --upsertFields <fieldname>
```

so for your case just

```
--mode merge --upsertFields
```

Answer (score 1):

New feature has been added since version 3.4 [Documentation here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Check this option

```
--mode insert|upsert|merge
```

In your case you can use this may be:

```
--mode merge
```